# Overriding Magento_RequisitionList Template

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override the content on /requisition_list/requisition/index/ in the account pages. I have created the following file -> app/design/frontend/[COMPANY]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_RequisitionList/frontend/templates/requisition/actions/create.phtml

create.phtml is copied over from vagrant/tmp/vendor/magento/module-requisition-list/view/frontend/templates/requisition/actions/create.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div class="title-actions-links" data-bind="scope: 'requisition.action.edit'">
    <button class="action add" type="button"
            data-bind="
                click: edit.bind($data, {}),
                visible: isCanCreateList()">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Create New Requisition List')) ?></span>
    </button>
</div>
<p>MESSAGE TO GO HERE</p>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "requisition.action.edit": {
                        "component": "Magento_RequisitionList/js/requisition/action/edit",
                        "editModuleName": "requisition.edit"
                    },
                    "requisition.edit": {
                        "component": "Magento_RequisitionList/js/requisition/list/edit",
                        "modal": "add_to_requisition_popup",
                        "saveUrl": "<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getUrl('rest/V1/requisition_lists') ?>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

but the changes are not visible on the front end. I have verified the template using by enabling theme hints, tried running setup:di:compile, flushed the cache, cleaned the cache, verified file permissions, etc. without no luck.

How can override content on this page?

Comment: Please add your code and path for all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this path, the second 'frontend' shouldn't be there :
`app/design/frontend/[COMPANY]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_RequisitionList/templates/requisition/actions/create.phtml`

Don't forget to clean your magento and browsers caches.

Comment: Thank you Vinz!!! That worked. I actually had tried this but I think I was thwarted by the browser cache.

Few helpful things I learned:  
  
bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable  [show templates to use on pages] . 
bin/magento cache:flush .

Comment: Nice to hear, don't forget to accept my answer !